# Using 32 bit COM objects in Windows Phone applications

Tags: com, windows-phone

Is it possible to use old-fashioned 32 bit COM objects in Windows Phone 8+ applications? We are talking about non-visual ones.

Comment: if you find regsvr32.exe - yes :)

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, this is not the only way to register a COM, it's simply a gateway to RegisterClass. But I take it your answer is, "no idea how"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows Phone 8.0 I'm not sure, but for 8.1 there is no law that can prevent that.

For 8.1 you need to envelope it in a C++/CX class and then use that class as a normal assemby added in References Project folder.

For 8.0 perhaps a C++ library for Windows Phone that can be then used by C# code.

However there is a rule: native integrated code must use only Unicode, and only has a subset of Win32 API available. They are listed here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207198(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207198%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Actually, inside it can work with ANSI: it looks like WideCharToMultiByte and MultiByteToWideChar are supported.

Comment: @VadimBerman The APIs are all Unicode.  WcToMB (and vice versa) are for converting incoming data to/from Unicode.

Comment: @EricBrown: do you see the difference between "native integrated code must use only Unicode" and "the APIs are all Unicode"? Because, you know, native integrated code is not all calls to Windows API.

Comment: @VadimBerman I do see the difference; in my coding, I end up passing data to some API, usually sooner rather than later.  If you're the kind of dev who reinvents APIs rather than using them, then I suppose that you can take longer to convert data to Unicode.

Comment: No, you don't see the difference. In your code, you have **some** API calls and lots of other code. If your / 3rd party component content is in ANSI, you still can work with it, having converted it from / to Unicode. If you still don't get it, nevermind.

Comment: Yes, that's right. In my own code I use a bunch of libraries that internally works in ANSI, but before offer some API to be used by WP, I need to convert them to Unicode and use an Unicode only API. 

You can verify if all is ok trying to upload to store a beta version of your app. If you are using any kind of not allowed API (ANSI or whatever other not authorized call), you can't upload your XAP.